# Meaning of keyword/modifier _seg in old C++ code

Tags: c++

I'm currently looking through some ancient C++ code (Borland C++ 3.1), precisely the Wolfenstein 3D open source code: https://github.com/id-Software/wolf3d

It uses a ?modifier? _seq, like this:

```cpp
byte        _seg    *audiosegs[NUMSNDCHUNKS];
```

I can't find any documentation of this in modern C++. Can anybody point me in the direction to what is does?

Comment: `_seg` or `_seq`?

Comment: It is `seg_` https://github.com/id-Software/wolf3d/blob/master/WOLFSRC/ID_CA.C#L60

Comment: *"I can't find any documentation of this in modern C++"* looks like wolf3d is built with borland C++3.0. You probably won't find anything remotely modern in there.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search led me to [this webpage](http://www.bobeager.uk/tonyingenoso/chap2.htm) that explains well what `_seg` does:

> Another special Borland extension is the _seg pointer type. _seg pointers are a type of pointer that maps directly to a segment or selector value with an implied offset of zero. An _seg pointer is a 16 bit variable. These are primarily useful for saving space in situations where you would normally have a "far" pointer where the 16 bit offset part of the pointer is always going to be zero. Using an _seg pointer in cases like this can memory sometimes because a normal "far" pointer would be 4 bytes.
>
> In a plain DOS program using an _seg pointer is an easy way to access a program's PSP (program segment prefix).

The usage of `_seg` seems like a way to save space on pointers.Wolfenstein 3D was a DOS application, and so it must have been plagued by the memory limitations typical of the MSDOS era.

A DOS application running in real mode could only access the first 640KiBs of RAM, which were known as *"conventional memory"*.

At the time people had to resort to any sort of weird shenanigans to save memory (like for instance moving MSDOS into a small chunk of memory above the conventional area, which was discovered as being usable), and technologies like EMS and XMS were used to circumvent this limit and allow applications to use more RAM, albeit with a sharp increase in complexity and the requirement for the user to correctly configure a memory manager like HIMEM.SYS or EMS386. This was especially true with EMS, which was pretty nasty hack based on bank switching.

Comment: Was listening to a piece on the music of the Wing Commander games the other day where two of the musicians, also fans of the games, reminisce about the hell that was freeing up sufficient memory to load the early games and get them running. Man, we live in such enlightened times. I can't wait to see the tools and capabilities available to my kids.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.bobeager.uk/tonyingenoso/chap2.htm

> ## _seg pointers
>
> Another special Borland extension is the _seg pointer type. _seg pointers are a type of pointer that maps directly to a
> segment or selector value with an implied offset of zero. An _seg
> pointer is a 16 bit variable. These are primarily useful for saving
> space in situations where you would normally have a "far" pointer
> where the 16 bit offset part of the pointer is always going to be
> zero. Using an _seg pointer in cases like this can memory sometimes
> because a normal "far" pointer would be 4 bytes.
>
> In a plain DOS program using an _seg pointer is an easy way to access
> a program's PSP (program segment prefix). Here's an example of an _seg
> pointer being used. For output, this program simply echos whatever
> parameters it was pass when it was run.
>
> ```
> #include <dos.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main(void)    
> {    
>      char _seg *pPSP;  /* an _seg pointer to our PSP */
>      char near *p;    unsigned char CmdLineLen;
>
>      /* _psp is initialized by the Borland startup code as being the segment address of this     program's PSP.    */    
>      pPSP = (void _seg *)_psp;    CmdLineLen = *(pPSP+128);    p = (char near *)129;
>
>    while (CmdLineLen--)
>       {
>       putchar(*(pPSP+p));
>       p++;
>       }    return 0;    
> }
> ```
>
> One of the convenient properties of _seg pointers is they can be
> combined with a "near" pointer when doing pointer arithmetic. The
> result of adding a near pointer to an _seg pointer is that a "far"
> pointer is generated. This is being done in the call to putchar() in
> the example program.

Answer (score 0):

> _seg pointers are a type of pointer that maps directly to a segment or selector value with an implied offset of zero.

Source: http://www.bobeager.uk/tonyingenoso/chap2.htm

Answer (score 0):

i did some research and the modern (at least open watcom C modern) equivalent is  __based( void )

i just simply defined it with

#define _seg __based( void )

check out where i used this code.
https://github.com/sparky4/16
https://github.com/sparky4/16-0
the other answers explain what is _seg. but this is the open watcom equivalent